# converter.json2csv(header) - Test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Trying to run a test for the following code using Jest Enzyme. The test is passing at the moment but i am not calling the method the right away.

```
downloadTemplate = () => {
  let header = '';
  switch(this.props.grid) {
    case 'Company':
      header = companyImportHeader;
    break;
    case 'Contact': 
      header = contactImportHeader;
    break;
    case 'Account':
      header = accountImportHeader;
    break;
 }

converter.json2csv(header, (err,CSV) => {
  CSV = str2ab("CSV") //error argument should be a string
  var blob = new Blob([CSV], { type: "text/csv" });
  if (blob) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, this.props.grid+"_Import_Template.csv")
  }
}, {emptyFieldValue: ''})
}
```

Here is what I have so far, theres an onClick event that calls download template method . Using shallow

```
it("should call click event on downloadTemplate - ", () => { 
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({
    grid:{}
  }); 
  wrapper.setState({
   }); 
  wrapper.update()    
  wrapper.find('#template-test-click').at(0).simulate("click");
})
```

Here is part of the render() where there are 2 click events. Trying to test the first one but not sure if the 2nd one is related to it as well.

```
</div>
  <div>
    <button className={'tran-button file-button'} id='template-test-click' onClick={() => {this.downloadTemplate()} }>
     Template
    </button>
     <label 
     for='file-input'
     id='' 
     onClick={() => {document.getElementById('file-input').value=''; document.getElementById('file-input').click(); }}
     className='tran-button file-button'
            >
```